# Is there a URL scheme to open a website in Microsoft Edge on iOS?

Tags: ios, microsoft-edge

I'm developing an iOS app and would like to offer to open web links in the Microsoft Edge app if the user has it installed. While the app will open with the `microsoft-edge:` scheme the result is that the app attempts to go to the full passed URL, `microsoft-edge:` protocol and all. That obviously isn't a valid address so it just displays an error.

The URL schemes for opening a link in Chrome or Firefox are well documented but I can't find anything for Edge. Is it possible to do this, or does the Edge app not support it at the moment?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use:

`microsoft-edge-http://` or `microsoft-edge-https://`

Answer (score 1):

- Unwrap the IPA file for Edge. An IPA is a ZIP archive so rename it to do it from Finder or unzip directly from command line.
- Find the `Info.plist`
- Examine the `Info.plist`. If a custom URL scheme exists it will be listed under `CFBundleURLTypes` > `CFBundleURLSchemes`